# Too many sessions are created when accessing the login page?

Tags: apache, spring, tomcat, spring-security

i am using spring framework,apache,tomcat 
and the login page is handled with spring security
and i have an issue
that every first time request to the login page is generating a new session for the user, i know it's the default behaviour, when you access the login page, a new session is created for you, then what if a large load made on the login page, too many users are just viewing the login page without doing anything, so too many un-used sessions are created here.
what do you guys think of just an issue, i know it's rare, but it may occur, how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think thats rare. One possible solute could be to set the session timeout to a minimum. For example 5 minutes. Further you can write a filter to increase the session timeout if a session already exists for the user. So normal user will have a session timeout of 30 minutes and users only visit one side have a timeout of 5 minutes.

Here is a filter that dose the trick:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;

    // The false is important, otherwise a new session will be created.
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);

    if (session == null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 * 60);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Another good advice is to filter crawlers like the google bot. "Bot Detection" is a good keyword to look for.

Comment: what if a logged in user have a session already, and he's being idle for 5 minutes, so his session will be destroyed too ?

Comment: Yes, if the user only make one request. Any further request will extend the timeout to 30*60 seconds.

Comment: great, i have another issue, in another app i had, there are many sessions with used time 0, how to manage them too ?

Comment: meaning every minute to validate sessions with used time zero, and leave the sessions that has used time more than zero, is the solution here is the same one too ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. What do you mean by "used time zero"?

Comment: in tomcat manager-the session administration there are some data like: Session Id   Guessed Locale   Guessed User name   Creation Time   Last Accessed Time   Used Time   Inactive Time   TTL..... the used time, is the time that session has been used, got me ?

Comment: OK, now I understand. The filter will help you with this problem too. As it is a general solution for sessions created and never used subseqently.